# Solving Des Chiffres Et Des Lettres - The total is right

Tags: code-golf, game

One of the games of the French TV show [Des chiffres et des lettres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Des_chiffres_et_des_lettres), called *Le compte est bon* ('The total is right'), consists of the following :

You get a number A between 101 and 999 as well as six numbers E1,..,E6 chosen randomly, with possible repetitions, from {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,25,50,75,100}

The goal is to get as close to A as possible by using the operations +,-,*,/ on E1,...,E6. Each number may only be used once, but you do not have to use them all. **The result of each operation must be a positive integer**

Example : A=859, E1,..,E6= 6, 75, 3, 6, 8, 9 -> Best result : 858=(((75+6)-(9-6))*(8+3))

---

Following that concept, here are the rules :

- Write a function that takes as argument a positive integer A and a list of positive integers L. The function returns a **string** showing the closest one can get to A, which we'll call B, using the numbers in L, in the format *B = operations* (ex for A=859 : "858=(((75+6)-(9-6))*(8+3)))", you may reduce the number of parenthesis as long as it remains clear).
- The only allowed operations are +,-,* and /. The result of each of the operations must be **positive integers**.
- Each number of L may only be used **once**, but you don't have to use all the numbers.

**This is code golf, the shortest code in bytes wins !**

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the total number of possible answers given 6 numbers and 4 operators?

Comment: @Compass I'm not sure, but the program I made in Python runs about 1500000 iterations (It's a pretty basic one)

Comment: It's not actually a duplicate, as this one is more constrained.  A winning answer here will probably not be general enough to qualify there, and a qualifying answer there will probably not win here.  Related, but not the same.